# TypeError: client.getReceiver is not a function in azure-iot-device-http examples

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using [azure-iot-device-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device-http), and runnint the getting started code:

```
var clientFromConnectionString = require('azure-iot-device-http').clientFromConnectionString;
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;
var connectionString = 'myHostname,myDevice,myKey;
var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var msg = new Message('some data from my device');

client.sendEvent(msg, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err.toString());
});

client.getReceiver(function (err, rcv) {
  rcv.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    rcv.complete(msg, function () {
      console.log('completed');
    });
  });
  rcv.on('errorReceived', function (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  });
});
```

But I am receiving this error:

> TypeError: client.getReceiver is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is an error in the libraries examples. It doesn't look like it defines `client.getReceiver`. You should probably commit a bug here: [github issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues).

Try to use

```
client._transport.getReceiver(function (err, rcv) {
```

as a workaround for

```
client.getReceiver(function (err, rcv) {
```

until they fix it in the library.